# WooCommerce - add description before woocommerce_form_field() on checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding some custom fields to my checkout page, with following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'bs_custom_checkout_fields' );
function bs_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'order_domain_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Name','bs'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter the name','bs'),
        'required'      => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'order_domain_name' ));
}
```

I would need to add some additional description before this field, to explain the user what this field means. Is there way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `description` parameter:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'bs_custom_checkout_fields' );
function bs_custom_checkout_fields( $checkout ) {

woocommerce_form_field( 'order_domain_name', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'         => __('Name','bs'),
    'placeholder'   => __('Enter the name','bs'),
    'required'      => true,
    'description    => __('Additional description goes here','bs')
), $checkout->get_value( 'order_domain_name' ));
```

}

Comment: Thanks, that almost works, the only problem being it adds description AFTER the field... Any chance to put it before the field? I'm currently using jQuery for this, but would prefer some nonJS solution..

Answer (score 2):

I found two options to fix this in a way that will be safe with WooCommerce updates.

One way is to use the filter 'woocommerce_form_field'.  This passes the $`field` variable as well as `$key`, `$args`, `$value` for the field.  You can edit the output, but this is a bit tedious and may need updating in the future.

A much more simple option is to change it through CSS by utilizing flexbox.  I added the following CSS code to move the description above the form fields:

```
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-input-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display:    -moz-box;
    display:         box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
       -moz-box-orient: vertical;
            box-orient: vertical;
    width: 100%;
}
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-input-wrapper .description {
    display:  -ms-flexbox;
    display:  -webkit-box; 
    display:     -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display:         flex;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
       -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
               -ms-flex-order: 1; 
                -webkit-order: 1; 
                        order: 1;
    font-style: italic;
}
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-input-wrapper input,
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-input-wrapper textarea,
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-input-wrapper .select2-container {
    display:  -ms-flexbox;
    display:  -webkit-box; 
    display:     -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display:         flex;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
       -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
               -ms-flex-order: 2; 
                -webkit-order: 2; 
                        order: 2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is in answer to putting the description underneath the label.

You need to hack `/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php`

Move the Line 2103 - `$field_html .= $field;`
to Line 2108.

That's all you can do, not WooCommerce update proof unfortunately.

Comment: Although technically possible, one should never edit 3rd party code which is subject to changes. Either you'll end up with a outdated codebase because you don't want to lose your "customizations", or - well - you lose your customizations and need to manually migrate them every time you update. Why is outdated codebase bad? Vulnerabilities may be found, which will be attacked right after they are published, and with time your project will become incompatible with other plugins, thus rendering it a PITA.